# .net 5 performance of Dictionary vs List vs other in large iteration

Tags: arrays, list, performance, dictionary, .net-5

I have an algorithm that works with 80,000 items and a dictionary, but the performance is not so good, so I'm looking at a way to optimize it, maybe I'm using the wrong list type?

The scenario, I have 80,000 map references that I need to group, based on how 'close' they are. If they're within X distance, then they get added to a group, or they're a new reference point.

Currently I use a Dictionary with the key = map reference, value = a list of references that are close (within X distance).

For 80,000 objects, that a lot of iterating and it takes minutes to complete.

Any thought so on this ?

Pseudo code.

```
dictionary (reference, list<references>) referenceGroup = new...

foreach (reference in references) {
    foreach (group in referenceGroup) {
        if (reference.distancefrom(group.key) <= X) {
            referenceGroup.value.add(reference)
            break
        }
    }
    if (neverAddedToGroup) {
        referenceGroup.add(reference, reference)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you mean to iterate over all items, why use a dictionary at all? Dictionaries are meant to accelerate lookups by storing items in buckets based on hash values. By definition, iterating over them is slower, that's not what they were made for

Comment: I understand, however, I use the index lookup of the dictionary to first detect if there is an exact map reference. if (dictionary.containsKey(reference)) = we have an exact match. By moving to a plain list I'd have to scan every entry.

Comment: You can use *both*. If you store reference types, a List or Dictionary only store a reference to the object, not the object itself.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What does `distanceFrom` do? You could use eg the [K-Means clustering algorithm from the ML.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/iris-clustering) library